# TCP send image, reassemble when it has arrived

Tags: c#, tcp

Okay i have currently been using UDP (love it), but i am reaching a bottleneck in it, as it´s not possible to send huge stuff. And it´s impossible to divide it and reassemble it from my understanding (well i can reassemble, but the parts will be our of sync).

If there is a way to do it in UDP, i am all ear.

But if not, i will need to try TCP.

And i wonder, how can i do it?

currently in UDP it´s pretty straightforward:

udpcap1.Send(u1, u1.Length, adress.Address.ToString(), 1701);

byte[] databyte2 = udpcap1.Receive(ref adress)

that´s pretty much it, (except that i have to set it up to listen to any IP and port).

But in TCP, it doesn´t seem to be that easy, i have no idea how to do it, and playing around got me nowhere, neither did searching as i don´t quite understand it.

I prefer to just use the Client, meaning no Socket to do the work.
Just Client Send, Client Receive.

Can you give me some help with how to send and receive in TCP?

Here is a sample of the code, which doesn´t work:

```
 private void Send()
     {
         if (tcpcap.Connected == false)
         {
             tcpcap.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1700);
         }   //tcpcap.Connect(adress);
         while (capcon == true)
         {
             Bitmap holder = new Bitmap(640, 480);
             Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(holder);
             graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(1920, 1200), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy); 
             byte[] u = imageToByteArray(holder);               
            tcpcap.Client.Send(u, u.Length, SocketFlags.None);
         }


  private void Listen()
    {
        while (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            TcpClient client = this.tcplisten.AcceptTcpClient();
            tcplisten.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (tcplisten.Server.Connected)
            {
            byte[] b = new byte[tcplisten.Server.ReceiveBufferSize];
            tcplisten.Server.Receive(b);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
            Image receivedImag = Image.FromStream(ms);
                pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = receivedImag;
            }               
 }
```

Comment: Just stream the bytes from the file to the socket at one end, and from the socket to the file at the other end. Nothing mysterious about it. Same code at both ends, apart from setting up the input and output.

Comment: I don´t know how to write it, that´s my problem. I am very new to c#, and just use sample codes any play around to understand. I need a more, "fail proof" example of sending receiving TCP, so i can get a kickstart. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, as i know understand more how TCP works.

As EJP says, just stream.

TCP works like a stream, and for me who has only used UDP, i didn´t get how to do that.
UDP sends packages, so i can say, this package contains that, and just send it.

In TCP i can write 100 packages in a stream, but i don´t care about the packages, i just write what i want to the Stream TCP will handle the package size and order.

So this is solved:)